# $ABCD$ right angle trapezoid

Tags: geometry

[image]

Let $ABCD$ be a right angle trapezoid, with angle $\hat{A} =90$ degrees and $\overline{AB}$ is parallel to $\overline{CD}$. Let $O$ be the intersection point of the diagonals $\overline{AC}$ and $\overline{BD}$. The parallel through $O$ to the basis intersects $\overline{AD}$ at $E$ (which lies on $\overline{AD}$). Prove that $\overline{EO}$ is the angle bisector of angle $\widehat{BEC}$.
(I believe the proof must be answered using Side Angle Side similarity between triangle $CDE$ and triangle $BAE$)

Comment: Mindlessly taking the first few words in the problem statement is NOT a way to produce a question title that will tell anyone anything about what the question is about!

Answer (score 1):

As $AB // EO // CD$, $\hat{CEO} = \hat{ECD}$ and $\hat{BEO} = \hat{EBA}$, so it's necessary to prove that $\hat{EBA} = \hat{ECD}$...

Let $\hat{EBA} = \alpha$, $\hat{ECD} = \beta$ and $F$ the intersection between $EO$ and $CB$. Notice that $ABO\cong CDO$ ($AB // CD$ and $\hat{AOB} = \hat{COD}$), so $$AB:CD=AO:OC=BO:OD$$
By applying $Thales'$ $Theorem$ you obtain that $$AE:ED=AO:OC$$ $$\to AO:OC=AB:CD=AE:ED$$ $$\to ED=\frac{AE\cdot CD}{AB}$$
Now, $$\tan\beta = \frac{ED}{CD} = \frac{AE\cdot CD}{AB}\frac{1}{CD} = \frac{AE}{AB} = \tan\alpha$$ $$\to \beta = \alpha$$ It can't be $\to \beta = \alpha \pm \pi$ because both $\beta$ and $\alpha$ are $\lt \frac{\pi}{2}$

$Q.E.D.$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Prove that $$\frac{AE}{DE}=\frac{BO}{DO}=\frac{AB}{CD}.$$

Comment: but $AE/ED=BO/DO$ so  if this equals $BO/EO$ then $EO=DO$ which is not true

Comment: @user126154 Sorry, I meant $BO/DO$ rather than $BO/EO$. You get the idea. I corrected the error.